# Pub Sub Cloud Function - Async Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Trying to accomplish the following via a scheduled Firebase Function:

1. Fetch Firestore Collection
2. Delete Collection
3. Make Get Request to External API
4. Write Get Request results to Firestore Collection.

The function is failing to deploy. Error logs only say `{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code.`

When I run the emulator suite locally, I get no errors, but the DB does not update.

I'm getting a linting error on the "=>" that's attached to the "onRun" method. Not sure if this is a code problem or an ESLint problem for ES6 in Firebase Functions.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const axios = require('axios');

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("every 2 minutes")
    .timeZone("America/New_York")
    .onRun(async (context) => {

      try {

        const querySnapshot = await db.collection("my_collection").get();
        console.log(querySnapshot.docs)
        const promises = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => db.collection("my_collection").doc(doc.id).delete());

        await Promise.all(promises);

        const options = {
          "method": "get",
          "url": "www.myUrl.com",
          "headers": {
            "Cookie": "...",
          },
        };

        const axiosResponse = await axios(options);
        const apiResponse = JSON.parse(axiosResponse.data);
        const parsedResponse = apiResponse["news_results"];

        const docCreationPromises = parsedResponse.map(response => db.collection("my_collection").add(parsedResponse))

        await Promise.all(docCreationPromises);

        return null;

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ESLint issue with `=>`, try setting the `ecmaVersion` to 8 in your ESLint config.

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 8
  }
};
```

> When I run the emulator suite locally, I get no errors, but the DB does not update.

Are you using Firestore emulator? If yes, then data will be added there and not in production so you can see the data in emulator only.

Comment: Thanks @Dharmaraj - that fixed the linting issue. But the deployment is still failing for the same reason. I'm seeing the same error message in the Firebase Function logs: `{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code.`

Wondering if I'm not resolving a promise correctly or something...?

Comment: @thebenCA can you try deleting `node_modules` and try again? If the issue still persists, please try `firebase deploy --only function --debug` and there share the ouptut

Comment: Thanks @Dharmaraj - looks like an IAM issue. I'm currently using the default service account. 

`{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}`

That give me some solid direction moving forward. Appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Don't know if it is in context to your solution but: if you set the id (out of api) for the object yourself instead of firestore is creating one. And use ```set``` instead of ```add``` firestore will overwrite the ones he found and creates the one's that are not found. Then you do not need to delete. Also the batch write (500 a time) will significantly increase perfomance.